# shinyapp make bold in ui

Tags: html, r, shiny

I would like to make a few bold words in UI in the sentence. I am not sure how [HTML tags](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/tag-glossary.html) will work under `h()`. any help will be appreciated. many thanks in advance.

```
library(shiny)
    ui <- navbarPage(
      title = 'Benvenuto',
      tabPanel('read.me', icon = icon("book-open"),  column(4,
                                                            
                                                            h3("Welcome to Interactive User Interface"),
                                                            
                                                            tags$b("Please wait/refresh.", style="color:red"),
    
                                                            h3("Table"),
                                                            h4("Pivot table."),
                                                            
                                                            h2("I HAVE A LONG SENTENCE HERE AND I WANT A FEW WORDS TO BE BOLD ONLY."),
                                                        
      )), 
    
      tabPanel('Table', icon = icon("table"), rpivotTableOutput("pivot") ),
      id="navbar" )
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
    
      output$pivot <- renderRpivotTable({
        rpivotTable(data =   mtcars,  
                    rows = "cyl",
                    cols = c("am", "gear", "carb"),
                    #vals = "Freq", aggregatorName = "Count", rendererName = "Table", subtotals = TRUE) # use this or below line
                    #aggregatorName = "Sum as Fraction of Columns", vals = "Freq", rendererName = "Table Barchart")
                    aggregatorName = "Sum as Fraction of Rows", vals = "cyl", rendererName = "Table With Subtotal")
        #width="200%", height="600px")
        
      })
    
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Expected Answer,
I HAVE A LONG SENTENCE **HERE** AND I WANT A **FEW WORDS** TO BE **BOLD** ONLY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `HTML` function to just use tags like this:

`HTML("<h2>I HAVE A LONG SENTENCE HERE AND I WANT <b>A FEW WORDS</b> TO BE BOLD ONLY.</h2>")`

Answer (score 2):

`h()` functions (or almost any html tag function) takes any number of arguments. You can compone your header how you want, including inserting bold words, variables, function results:

```r
library(htmltools)


var <- 'Variable'
f <- function(x) {
  x + 42
}

h4("I HAVE A LONG SENTENCE",
   tags$s("HERE"),
   "AND I WANT",
   tags$i( f(4), "WORDS"),
   "TO BE ",
   tags$b("BOLD"),
   "ONLY,",
   "AND A VARIABLE: ",
   code(var))
```

I HAVE A LONG SENTENCE
<s>HERE</s>
AND I WANT

*46
WORDS*

TO BE
**BOLD**
ONLY,
AND A VARIABLE:
`Variable`

<sup>Created on 2020-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>